# Search in very large SVN remote project

Tags: maven, unix, svn, search

I'm working in a very large project. I need to perform a search in all pom.xml files under a trunk folder (I've a hundred different trunk folder) in order to find if it contains a certain dependency.

I can't donwload all the svn repository, so I need to make a remote search. Is there a efficient way to do it ?

I think I should locate trunk folders, then search all pom.xml files into them before grep'ing their content to find my dependency, but I don't know how to do it on remote server :/

Answer (score 2):

- `svn ls -R` in the root of tree, grep needed files, construct full URL
- `svn cat URL/OF/FILE | grep PATTERN` for each file

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of Find and Grep command. Similar to (not exact)

```
grep -R "192.168.1.5" /etc/
```

or with combination with Find command

```
find . -name “*.xml” |xargs grep -n “bla”
```

see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/)